# Find latest (date) entry

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to bring back a score associated with a company but I only want the latest entry. If there is no score at all, I want the cell to be blank.

| Companies | Score | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3.5 | 2/1/2020 |
| A | 4.3 | 1/16/2019 |

In this case, if I wanted Company A's score, I would like it to return the 3.5. If I am looking up Company D, I would like the cell to remain blank.

Thank you so much for any help in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

IF one has the Dynamic Array formula SORTBY and FILTER:

```
=@SORTBY(FILTER(B:B,A:A=E1,""),FILTER(C:C,A:A=E1,""),-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, this does not seem to be working. Getting #VALUE!

Comment: do you have FILTER and SORTBY?  They are only available with subscription to Office 365 Excel or office 365 online.

Comment: Yes, I have a subscription. I am referencing data on different sheets, I dont know if that matters.

Comment: Then you need to change the references to reference the data correctly.

Comment: Yes, of course. Still no luck. Not sure what the problem is. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Please post the formula you tried as is. Do not translate or change.

Answer (score 0):

Use `XLOOKUP()`:

```
=XLOOKUP(F2,  SORTBY(A2:A41, C2:C41),  SORT(C2:C41),  "",  0,  -1)
```

`SORTBY()` puts your lookup array, A2:A41 in the formula, into order sorted by column C, the column you want values from. You are sorting it so that the last instance of the lookup value `XLOOKUP()` would find if searching from top to bottom will be the one you want it to be, not a random entry.

You are ensuring this by sorting BY your return value column, column C in this case (so C2:C41 in the formula) in the ascending direction, that is, lowest of its values first, highest of them last. Since there are dates in that column, and Excel regards dates as numbers, this causes no difficulties.

So at this point Excel sees the data range with the highest value date, the latest date, for each set of lookup range values, at the end of the virtual data range that has been created.

`XLOOKUP()` is then told to search from the end to the beginning (bottom to top) and so when it finds the lookup value it is given, it finds the last of them in any set of those values in the formula's virtual data range. So it will return the corresponding record in the also virtual results column. Since that was also sorted, with just `SORT()` this time since it needs no more, and since the two sorts were done by the same "sort by" column, the record in column C will match the original record from column A:  in other words, the rows of pairs from the two columns stayed together rather than becoming a mixed up mess.

So you created a virtual data range of the lookup array and the results array in which the pairs stayed matched up. You sorted the two arrays so that each lookup value grouped with its similar values ensuring, because of the sorting by the results array, that the last one of them will be the one you want. And since `XLOOKUP()` can look from end to beginning, it is findable.

Actually, you could do the sorting in the descending direction, highest date to lowest date for each set of identical lookup values. Then you could use `XLOOKUP()` to look from beginning to end if you had some reason for that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).